# Print Block Regions inside layout template (Drupal 8 template)

Tags: templates, twig, drupal-8

I would like to print a block region inside a layout file. However the layout template doesnt have access to the **'page'** variable. So I cannot do:

```
{{ page.regionname }}
```

Is there any code to print block regions? Oooor how can I get the **page** variable in one of my layouts? The layout and template file is defined in my yml file as follows:

```
services_overview:
  label: services - Overview
  category: ssld Layouts
  template: templates/layouts/ssld-hs-overview
  regions:
    sidebar_left:
      label: Sidebar Left
    right:
      label: Right
    left:
      label: Left
    middle:
      label: Middle
```

(It might be worth mentioning that I'm not too familiar with twig. This is the first time I work with Drupal 8)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the regions in page.html.twig file as `{{page.sidebar_left}}`. Your your_theme.info.yml file should look something like this

```
name: Bartik
type: theme
base theme: classy
description: 'A flexible, recolorable theme with many regions and a responsive, mobile-first layout.'
package: Core
version: VERSION
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - bartik/global-styling
regions:
  sidebar_left: 'Sidebar Left'
  right: 'Right'
  left: Left
  content: Content
  middle: 'Middle'
```

Above is a sample from bartik theme info file. A.F.A.I.K content region is mandatory

Comment: I know I have access to the page variable in page.html..twig. But that does not work because this content needs to be in a specific position inside a layout. And layout files dont have access to page for some reason

Comment: In which file you need to have the region variable provide more details

Comment: templates/layouts/ssld-hs-overview.html.twig

 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a three column layout.
 *
 * This template provides a three column 40%-20%-40% display layout.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - content: The content for this layout.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the layout <div>.